# Testing a Condition Before Creating an Observation in SAS using '@' in the end of the input statement

Tags: sas

I have read the online document and from it, I think that it only works with the column input method. How can this be used with list input method?

/*This Works*/

```
data new;

    input height 25-26 @;
    if height = 6 ;
    input name $ 1-8 colour $ 9-13 place $ 16-24 ;
    datalines;

Deepak  Red    Delhi    6
Aditi   Yellow Delhi    5
Anup    Blue   Delhi    5
Era     Green  Varanasi 5
Avinash Black  Noida    5
Vivek   Grey   Agra     5
;
run;
```

/* But This Doesn't*/

```
data new;

    input height @;
    if height = 6;
    input name $ colour $ place $ height;
    datalines;

Deepak Red Delhi 6
Aditi Yellow Delhi 5
Anup Blue Delhi 5
Era Green Varanasi 5
Avinash Black Noida 5
Vivek Grey Agra 5
;
run;

LOG:
NOTE: Invalid data for height in line 79 1-6.
 79         Deepak  Red    Delhi    6
height=. name=  colour=  place=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
 NOTE: Invalid data for height in line 80 1-5.
80         Aditi   Yellow Delhi    5
height=. name=  colour=  place=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
```

Comment: Did you look at the log ? Are there messages you can add to the question ?

Comment: Added. I should have looked at the log first, as they are self-explanatory. I'll take care of this from next time. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The fixed layout of the first data lines make it possible to input a field from a specific location.

The second layout is variable in layout, so it is harder to arbitrarily grab a specific field.

So, what is wrong? In the second DATA step the `input` will read from the start of the line, so it won't read a number from where a name is.

Don't worry about 'reducing processing' by reading only part of a line.  Held input and conditional processing is more often used for processing data lines that have some sort of variant or conditional data items within the content.

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked at the logs and it was right there. I am going through the PDF provided by SAS, "Step-by-Step Programming with Base SAS® 9.4, Second Edition" for learning SAS. Here I encountered this. If you could suggest me some other resources that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For both of those formats I would read all of the variables and then add logic to filter based on values.

If you really need to check if the last "word" on the line matched some criteria before deciding HOW to read the line then you might want to try using the automatic `_infile_` variable.

```
data new;
  input @ ;
  if scan(_infile_,-1,' ') = '6';
  input name $ colour $ place $ height;
datalines;
Deepak Red Delhi 6
Aditi Yellow Delhi 5
Anup Blue Delhi 5
Era Green Varanasi 5
Avinash Black Noida 5
Vivek Grey Agra 5
;
```

Comment: I would do that from the next time. Thanks.